# How do I make a CSS document that anyone can use?

Tags: html, css, linker

In case you don't understand what I mean, how do I create a CSS library that anyone can use? I mean this like, w3.css. You would link it like:

```
<link href="get code here" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Can someone please help? If it's confusing just tell please!

Comment: Place your CSS file on public server and share the address to the file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to upload your CSS file on a server. (Use an Apache server e.g)

Example:
Your server's domain is example.com. If you put the CSS file in the folder called 'cssfiles' and call the file itself "free.css", the link for the CSS file which you would use in the 'href=""' part would be http://example.com/cssfiles/free.css.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have a web server which contains the file. So if your website is `http://example.com` then on your server have the file at `http://example.com/yourfile.css`, that way other people could use it in their `HTML` files by having the following.

```
<link href="http://example.com/yourfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```